# Python Warning Panda Dataframe "Simple Issue!" - "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

first post / total Python novice so be patient with my slow understanding!

I have a dataframe containing a list of transactions by order of transaction **date**.

I've appended an additional new field/column called **["DB/CR"]**, that dependant on the presence of "-" in the ["Amount"] field populates 'Debit', else 'Credit' in the absence of "-".

Noting the transactions are in date order, I've included another new field/column called [Top x]. The output of which is I want to populate and incremental independent number (starting at 1) for both debits and credits on a segregated basis.

As such, I have created a simple loop with a associated 'if' / 'elif' (prob could use else as it's binary) statement that loops through the data sent row 0 to the last row in the df and using an if statement 1) "Debit" or 2) "Credit" increments the number for each independently by "Debit" 'i' integer, and "Credit" 'ii' integer.

**The code works as expected in terms of output** of the 'Top x'; however, I always receive a warning "*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame*".

Trying to perfect my script, **without any warnings** I've been trying to understand what I'm doing incorrect but not getting it in terms of my use case scenario.

Appreciate if someone can kindly shed light on / propose how the code needs to be refactored to avoid receiving this error.

Code (the df source data is an imported csv):

```
#top x debits/credits
i = 0
ii = 0
for ind in df.index:
    if df["DB/CR"][ind] == "Debit":
        i = i+1
        df["Top x"][ind] = i
    elif df["DB/CR"][ind] == "Credit":
        ii = ii+1
        df["Top x"][ind] = ii
```

Interpreter

```
  df["Top x"][ind] = i
G:\Finances Backup\venv\Statementsv.03.py:173: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["Top x"][ind] = ii
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for the error message?  I know for a fact there is a well-traveled SO post on this very matter.  Have a look.

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: thank you @ShodaiThox - also pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn' suppressing the warnings works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). Did you follow the [link to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) written in the traceback? It explains precisely the problem. Btw Rene's answer is the solution to your problem, not Naveed's...

Comment: Setting `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment=None` is ignoring the problem, not solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `df.loc["DB/CR", ind] = "Debit"`

Comment: my original response was removed, assumption as I ticked both answers!

Answer (score 0):

Use iterrows() to iterate over the DF. However, updating DF while iterating is not preferable

see documentation here

Refer to the documentation here [Iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html?highlight=iterrows#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows)

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not
> guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
> iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
> effect.

Comment: thank you - I used a different approach in other instances of my code where I would store the index's in a list and then affect the df post interrogating the column values, e.g.
s = df.index[df['Original Description'].str.contains("PFS", na=False)].tolist()
for i in s:
df.loc[i, ["Category"]] = "Fuel"